# Update all rows in a column in php

Tags: php, sql-update

I want to update all rows of a specific column on a table.
I have a `table` named `user` and a `column` named `type`. I want to `update` the data of all rows in column `type` with the value `faculty`.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: put your code. what you tried so far?

Comment: Which sql language are you using?

Comment: im using php with mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL with PHP:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET type = 'faculty'");
```

If you're using postgreSQL with PHP:

```
pg_query("UPDATE user SET type = 'faculty'");
```

Otherwise you can use

```
UPDATE user SET type = 'faculty'
```

with whichever SQL client you're using in the SQL query box.

Answer (score 2):

This will be your sql statement

```
sql = "UPDATE user SET type='faculty'";
```

then execute your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
mysql_query("update user set type = 'faculty'")or die();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

UPDATE user SET colum_name = "update_value" WHERE type= "faculty";